# Porque no se puede romper el bucle for con un if y en bucle while si

Tags: javascript

Siempre me pregunte porque se usa while y porque un for y aparte de todo lo que he encontrado en la web mi pregunta es:
//Porque esto=>

```
    function main() {
      var depth = parseInt(readLine(),10);   
    //variables
    var days=0;
    var total= 0;
    for(i=0;i<depth;i+=7){
        days++;      
        if(i>=depth){
            console.log(days);
            break;
        }
        i-=2;
    }
}
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------
//No puede ser igual a esto ?=>

```
 function main() {
    var depth = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    //your code goes here
    var day = 0;
    var total = 0;
    while(total<depth){
        day = day + 1;
        total = total + 7;
        if(total >= depth){
            console.log(day);
            break;
        }
        total = total - 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Que yo sepa, todos los bucles cuentan con las sentencias `continue`, `break`. Puedes hacer la misma tarea usando un `for` o un `while` solo debes verificar la lógica

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que la condición del if no se cumple nunca, porque cuando se inicia cada iteración del bucle, se comprueba que i < depth, con lo que cuando esto pasa, el bucle termina.

```js
function main() {
  var depth = 50;   
  var days=0;
  var total= 0;
  for(i=0; console.log(i) || i<depth; i+=7){
      days++;      
      if(i>=depth){
          console.log("salimos", days);
          break;
      }
      i-=2;
  }
}

main()
```

Si hacemos que la condición de salida del bucle sea distinta a la del if, obtenemos otro resultado:

```js
function main() {
  var depth = 50;   
  var days=0;
  var total= 0;
  for(i=0; console.log(i) || i<depth; i+=7){
      days++;      
      if(i >= depth / 2){
          console.log("salimos", days);
          break;
      }
      i-=2;
  }
}

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

En si ambos bucles pueden ser finalizados con sentencias tales como `continue` o `break`;

El detalle es que los bucles tales como los has planteado tienen comportamientos diferentes. Por ejemplo:

En el bucle relacionado al while

```
function main() {
var depth = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
//your code goes here
var day = 0;
var total = 0;
while(total<depth){
    day = day + 1;
    total = total + 7; //Dentro del ciclo estas realizando la suma del valor total en 7 unidades.
    if(total >= depth){
        console.log(day);
        break;
    }
    total = total - 2;
}
}
```

Mientras en el bucle `for`, estas pidiendo que luego de realizar todos los pasos dentro del bucle se sume en 7 unidades a tu contador.

```
function main() {
      var depth = parseInt(readLine(),10);   
    //variables
    var days=0;
    var total= 0;
    for(i=0;i<depth;i+=7){
        days++;      
        if(i>=depth){
            console.log(days);
            break;
        }
        i-=2;
    }
}
```

Un caso particular es que si depth toma el valor de 10, ingresa al ciclo `for` puesto que es menor i es 0 y depth = 10; restas 2 unidades y dado que ya acabó el ciclo `for` se suma 7 unidades, es decir para el próximo ciclo tendrias i =5 depth = 10; acabando el ciclo tendrías i=10 y depth = 10, por ende ya no entraría al ciclo `for`. Con ello quiero dar a entender que jamás entra a la validación de tu `if`. Mientras que en tu ciclo `while`, si hace la validación dado que la suma se realiza dentro del bloque y no al finalizar este como en un ciclo `for`.

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias, entonces seria  "for(i=0; i<depth; i++){days++; total+=7; if(total>=depth){console.log(days); break; } total-=2; }"

Comment: De hecho en este ultimo caso tambien tendrias un valor no esperado, mi recomendación seria de la siguiente forma: for(i=0;i<depth;i-=2){
        days++; i+= 7;      
        if(i>=depth){
            console.log(days);
            break;
        }
    }
}. Si la respuesta te sirvió no olvides marcarla como respuesta. Saludos